# How to add multiple components in a single row in Smartedit (SAP Commerce)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

We have Pages usually consisting of 3 content slots (header, content, footer). Also we are using a lot of custom components. Those were working fine in WCMS. With the upgrade to Smartedit they still work, but in smartedit the edit container is not covering the content element, because those custom components have flexible widths (so that multiple components can be in 1 row).

Smartedit wraps a div around the custom components that messes up those edit overlays. Is there any way to make the smartedit wrapper the same size as its components?

Or is there a better way to have multiple components in a single row in smartedit?

Answer (score 0):

create a new custom Component with include a list of your component.